# Cannot retain dropdown value after form submit in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am working in codeigniter and using dropdown to populate values in select2 jquery dropdown,
but the issue is i cannot retain the selected value after form submit, after using det_value it shows id not text.
Here is my code:

```
$name = array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name','class'=>' form-control');
echo form_dropdown($tutor_name,set_value('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the `'name'=>'name'` to `'name'=>'tutor_name'`,

refer this link and change the code according to the format given:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html